# Emacs ESS R - Message Content Encoding and Display Issue

Tags: character-encoding, ess

I use Emacs ESS for doing some work in R. But somehow the help messages or content which is output of R process, is not printed correctly, most likely because of some encoding issue. (Screenshot included below)
[image]

But if I do the same using the R console, it works fine as seen below:
[image]

Any advise how to fix the encoding issue in Emacs ESS.

Comment: It looks like the font Emacs is using doesn't have all the symbols R is trying to print. What version of Emacs, and what operating system are you using? The first thing I'd try is `M-x menu-set-font`. If you can find the same font that your terminal uses that might fix things.

Comment: I am using Emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 17.10. When I tried `M-x menu-set-font`, I am getting a message `Window System Frame should be used`. I am not sure whether that is a problem.