# R in ESS outputs UTF-8, which emacs renders raw

Tags: ess, character-encoding, r, utf-8

I find the question but no answer at [Emacs ESS R - Message Content Encoding and Display Issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42233/emacs-ess-r-message-content-encoding-and-display-issue?newreg=1258e16a652a4da6938464140a54ad96).

In buffer *R*, the R process uses UTF-8 encoding for its output.  However emacs does not decode that output, but displays it as-is.  E.g., I see this:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into â\200\230/home/brech/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0â\200\231
(as â\200\230libâ\200\231 is unspecified)
```

Obviously the cryptic looking `â\200\230` and `â\200\231`, which represent the code points "left single quotation mark" and "right single quotation mark" should look like single quotes.  I'd be happy with `'`.

BTW, `\200` `\231` and `\230` are rendered as `€`, `˜`, and `™` in Chrome.

So is there a way to either have R not UTF-8-encode, or to have emacs decode and render it legibly?